how to fix video player exo player issue?
PlatformException(VideoError, Video player had error com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: MediaCodecVideoRenderer error, index=0, format=Format(1, null, null, video/avc, avc1.640032, -1, null, [2732, 1440, 25.0], [-1, -1]), format_supported=NO_EXCEEDS_CAPABILITIES, null, null)
Failed to initialize decoder: OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc
W/MediaCodecRenderer(23564):   android.media.MediaCodec$CodecException:
W/MediaCodecRenderer(23564):       at android.media.MediaCodec.native_configure(Native Method)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(23564):       at android.media.MediaCodec.configure(MediaCodec.java:2332)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(23564):       at android.media.MediaCodec.configure(MediaCodec.java:2248)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(23564):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.AsynchronousMediaCodecAdapter.initialize(AsynchronousMediaCodecAdapter.java:156)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(23564):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.AsynchronousMediaCodecAdapter.access$100(AsynchronousMediaCodecAdapter.java:50)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(23564):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.AsynchronousMediaCodecAdapter$Factory.createAdapter(AsynchronousMediaCodecAdapter.java:103)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(23564):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.DefaultMediaCodecAdapterFactory.createAdapter(DefaultMediaCodecAdapterFactory.java:111)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(23564):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.initCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1099)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(23564):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodecWithFallback(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1010)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(23564):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodecOrBypass(MediaCodecRenderer.java:537)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(23564):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1453)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(23564):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:917)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(23564):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.readSourceOmittingSampleData(MediaCodecRenderer.java:954)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(23564):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:769)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(23564):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:1007)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(23564):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:502)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(23564):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(23564):       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(23564):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(23564):       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
Video codec error
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(23564):   com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer$DecoderInitializationException: Decoder init failed: OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc, Format(1, null, null, video/avc, avc1.640032, -1, null, [2732, 1440, 25.0], [-1, -1])
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(23564):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodecWithFallback(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1021)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(23564):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodecOrBypass(MediaCodecRenderer.java:537)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(23564):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1453)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(23564):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:917)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(23564):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.readSourceOmittingSampleData(MediaCodecRenderer.java:954)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(23564):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:769)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(23564):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:1007)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(23564):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:502)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(23564):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(23564):       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(23564):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(23564):       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(23564):   Caused by: android.media.MediaCodec$CodecException:
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(23564):       at android.media.MediaCodec.native_configure(Native Method)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(23564):       at android.media.MediaCodec.configure(MediaCodec.java:2332)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(23564):       at android.media.MediaCodec.configure(MediaCodec.java:2248)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(23564):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.AsynchronousMediaCodecAdapter.initialize(AsynchronousMediaCodecAdapter.java:156)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(23564):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.AsynchronousMediaCodecAdapter.access$100(AsynchronousMediaCodecAdapter.java:50)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(23564):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.AsynchronousMediaCodecAdapter$Factory.createAdapter(AsynchronousMediaCodecAdapter.java:103)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(23564):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.DefaultMediaCodecAdapterFactory.createAdapter(DefaultMediaCodecAdapterFactory.java:111)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(23564):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.initCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1099)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(23564):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodecWithFallback(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1010)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(23564):       ... 11 more
Playback error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(23564):   com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: MediaCodecVideoRenderer error, index=0, format=Format(1, null, null, video/avc, avc1.640032, -1, null, [2732, 1440, 25.0], [-1, -1]), format_supported=NO_EXCEEDS_CAPABILITIES
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(23564):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:578)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(23564):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(23564):       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(23564):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(23564):       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(23564):   Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer$DecoderInitializationException: Decoder init failed: OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc, Format(1, null, null, video/avc, avc1.640032, -1, null, [2732, 1440, 25.0], [-1, -1])
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(23564):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodecWithFallback(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1021)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(23564):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodecOrBypass(MediaCodecRenderer.java:537)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(23564):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1453)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(23564):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:917)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(23564):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.readSourceOmittingSampleData(MediaCodecRenderer.java:954)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(23564):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:769)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(23564):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:1007)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(23564):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:502)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(23564):       ... 4 more
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(23564):   Caused by: android.media.MediaCodec$CodecException:
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(23564):       at android.media.MediaCodec.native_configure(Native Method)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(23564):       at android.media.MediaCodec.configure(MediaCodec.java:2332)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(23564):       at android.media.MediaCodec.configure(MediaCodec.java:2248)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(23564):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.AsynchronousMediaCodecAdapter.initialize(AsynchronousMediaCodecAdapter.java:156)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(23564):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.AsynchronousMediaCodecAdapter.access$100(AsynchronousMediaCodecAdapter.java:50)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(23564):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.AsynchronousMediaCodecAdapter$Factory.createAdapter(AsynchronousMediaCodecAdapter.java:103)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(23564):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.DefaultMediaCodecAdapterFactory.createAdapter(DefaultMediaCodecAdapterFactory.java:111)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(23564):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.initCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1099)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(23564):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodecWithFallback(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1010)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(23564):       ... 11 more
I/flutter (23564): error of play video :: PlatformException(VideoError, Video player had error com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: MediaCodecVideoRenderer error, index=0, format=Format(1, null, null, video/avc, avc1.640032, -1, null, [2732, 1440, 25.0], [-1, -1]), format_supported=NO_EXCEEDS_CAPABILITIES, null, null)
